# Get link in popup window (python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get a link in a popup window of this page.
http://stivconsultasexternas.cnbv.gob.mx/ConsultaInformacionEmisoras.aspx
Clicking the first link that appears the page show us a popup window. I like to get the link inside of thin window.

Here is my code. I appreciate any help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stivconsultasexternas.cnbv.gob.mx/ConsultaInformacionEmisoras.aspx")
link=driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(u"Verum")
time.sleep(5)
link[0].click()
time.sleep(5)
print driver.page_source.encode("utf_8","ignore")#Here I want a html of a popup window.
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that the popup is in an `iframe`.  Selenium can only access the current content, anything in a child `iframe` is inaccessible.  In order to allow Selenium to access the new `iframe`, you'll need to use `switch_to.frame`:

```
link[0].click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("DefaultPlaceholder_callbackPanel_Popup_CIF-1")
print driver.page_source.encode("utf_8","ignore")#Here I want a html of a popup window.
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='DefaultPlaceholder_callbackPanel_Popup_HCB-1']").click()
```

Edit #1:

I looked at the page, and found the popin you wanted to access was contained in this `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="DefaultPlaceholder_callbackPanel_Popup_CIF-1" title="" src="/Detalle.aspx?enc=vxwQ2MoMebbVt2C93KNYJA%3d%3d" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" style="height: 578px; width: 100%;">
```

`switch_to.frame()` can accept the following as an identifier:
- The `name` or `id` of the `iframe`.  I used this particular case, since the `iframe` in question has `id="DefaultPlaceholder_callbackPanel_Popup_CIF-1"`
- The index of the `iframe`.  That would looks something like `switch_to.frame(0)`
- The `iframe` element.  You could find the `iframe` element via a `find_element_by_` locator, then use the `webelement` result of that in `switch_to.frame(el)`

Edit #2:

To close the dialog, you need to use `switch_to.default_content()`, as the close button is outside of the `iframe`.  You can then click the close button of the dialog, and proceed.  See the last line in the code above, that line should close the dialog for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. if is not inconvenient for you cuan you explain me how did you know that for this popup the frame is DefaultPlaceholder_callbackPanel_Popup_CIF-1? Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry one last question. How can I close the frame that now is opened. Because i want to use for for open many frames. I suppose that when one frame is opened I can't open another frame link. Thank you so much.